# Cannot open a file with white spaces in its name from the console. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have installed WineHQ on my Ubuntu. I want to run Balsamiq

```
~/Downloads/Balsamiq_Mockups_3$ ls -1
Adobe AIR
balsamiq_mockups_3.5.15.swf
Balsamiq Mockups 3.exe
framework_4.6.0.23201.swf
icons
META-INF
mimetype
skins
textLayout_2.0.0.232.swf
```

If I go for

```
 wine Balsamiq Mockups 3.exe
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Balsamiq.exe"
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes,it works,I will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
wine Balsamiq\ Mockups\ 3.exe
```